# TabLayout ViewPager Clear Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` has two tab items A and B.

When I hit tab A it shows me the correct view, same for tab B. Now in Tab A, I display a few `Fragment`'s A1(default)->A2->A3. When I hit tab B and then come back to Tab A, I can still see A3. How can I go to `Fragment` A1 each time I hit Tab A? I’m not sure where to add this logic (`ViewPager` or on the `TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener`) and default to the A1 `Fragment`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From A1>A2>A3 this is the way I'm replacing the fragments.

just call the **replace fragment** with same container of all three fragments.

```java
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, int container, String tag) {
    mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(containerId, fragment, tag);
    mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

And for back press button : 
     remove fragment this way

```java
public void removeFragment() {
    mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    mFragmentManager.popBackStack();
}
```

Here whenever you go to B tab and come back to A, state of fragment A3 is destroyed, hope this helps.